# Going Insane with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

To put it lightly, skinning this beast is a bit of a nightmare.

In any case, I'm trying to add the the textName of a dialog window to its container as a class to make my life easier.

I'm doing *something* wrong, as it won't seem to work for me. Any ideas? I've tried it the jQuery way too, with no success.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev){
                    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
                    var dialogBox = document.querySelector('table.cke_1_dialog');
                    dialogBox.setAttribute("class", dialogName);
                });
```

Comment: Do you know how to debug in the browser? If yes, set a break-point and check the values of `dialogName`, and `dialogBox`...

Comment: Thanks - it appears that this event fires too early for me to actually manipulate the dialog window, as it hasn't been added to the DOM yet. Anyone know a better event to listen to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev){
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    ev.data.definition.onLoad = labeler;
    function labeler(){
        var dialogBox = document.querySelector('table.cke_dialog');
        dialogBox.className = dialogBox.className + " " + dialogName;
    }
});
```

Comment: No need to declare a separate function here. Just assign a function expression: `ev.data.definition.onLoad = function () { var dialogBox... };`